# Access Combobox selectedText in WPF Datagrid column header?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a WPF `DataGrid` that is pretty standard, except the headers are not text, but a `ComboBox` control.

Here is a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image]

Goes without saying that there could be multiple columns. The columns are created programatically.

What I would like to do is traverse the column headers, and get the selectedText for each combobox.

How is this done?

EDIT:

The code I would expect to be writing would be along these lines:

```
foreach (DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader in columnHeaders)
{
    var combobox = (combobox) columnHeader.controls[0];
    var theDroidIAmLookingFor = combobox.Text;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know how you get the Combobox in the ColumnHeader but I assume via ColumnHeaderStyle, so my approach would be binding the SelectedValueProperty to a Property in your CodeBehind or ViewModel

```
<ComboBox x:Name="headerComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=headerSource}">
<ComboBox.SelectedValue>
    <Binding Path="HeaderSelectedValue" Mode="TwoWay" />
</ComboBox.SelectedValue>
```

**EDIT:**
C# Solution (not tested)

```
foreach (var column in myGrid.Columns)
{
    var colHeader = (DependencyObject)column.Header;
    var headerComboBox = colHeader.GetChildOfType<ComboBox>();
    var selected = headerComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

and here is the ExtensionMethod GetChildOfType

```
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) return null;
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** if you define the ColumnHeader like this

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="250">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <ComboBox Width="200">
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Test1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Test2"/>
            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

then column.Header would actually be the combobox so no need for going down the visualtree you could just cast it to combobox

```
var colHeader = (Combobox)column.Header;
```

maybe you could show me how you define the comboboxes in your columnheader

Comment: edited the answer, have not tested the code but it should work something like this

Comment: Ok props to you.... I modified your code a bit will post, will update your answer...

Comment: thanks :) and yup maybe you could/should summarize it to the essentials